# Как выполнить парсинг строки на kotlin?

Tags: строки, kotlin

Изучаю kotlin, и возник вопрос, как сделать на котлине парсинг строки типа: `/1значение/2значение/`.

Comment: Поясните. Пример входной строки и что в ней нужно напарсить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто разбиваем строку по разделителю:

```
fun main() {
    val str = "/1значение/2значение/"
    // Разбиваем по разделителю, получаем массив строк:
    val parts = str.split("/")
    // Выводим полученный массив
    println(parts) // [, 1значение, 2значение, ]  // Два пустых элемента (пустых строки) - в начале и в конце
    // Вывести все непустые элементы:
    for(part in parts) {
        if(part.length > 0) {
            println(part)
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
[, 1значение, 2значение, ]
1значение
2значение
```

Другой вариант: последовательно получаем элементы через [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val scan = Scanner("/1значение/2значение/").useDelimiter("/")
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        println(scan.next())
    }
}
```

Или так:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val scan = Scanner("/1значение/2значение/").useDelimiter("/")
    for(part in scan) {
        println(part)
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
1значение
2значение
```

Вообще, если не находите как сделать что-то в Kotlin, гуглите как это же сделать в Java - в большинстве случаев то же решение будет применимо и для Kotlin (как с тем же `Scanner`), т.к. в Kotlin используются те же стандартные библиотеки. Для более сложных вещей могут быть отдельные библиотеки для Kotlin и Java, но для простого (типа парсинга строк) будут применяться одни и те же инструменты.